# Accessing environment varaibles from NuGet.config on Docker Build Image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, .net-6.0

I need to use a NuGet PAT to restore nuget packages from a private feed.

```
<packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="MyPrivatePackage" value="http://<PRIVATE_PACKAGE_URL>/index.json" />
    <add key="nuget" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
</packageSources>
<packageSourceCredentials>
    <PackageSTN>
        <add key="Username" value="%NUGET_USER%" />
        <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="%NUGET_PAT%" />
        <add key="ValidAuthenticationTypes" value="basic" />
    </PackageSTN>
</packageSourceCredentials>
<activePackageSource>
    <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
</activePackageSource>
</configuration>
```

I have the following in my Docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
ARG pat_token
ENV NUGET_PAT="${pat_token}"

RUN echo "The ARG variable value is ${pat_token}"
RUN echo "ENV Variable is $NUGET_PAT"

WORKDIR /src
COPY ["NuGet.config", "."]
COPY ["MyProjFolder/myproj.csproj", "MyProjFolder/"]
RUN dotnet restore "MyProjFolder/myproj.csproj" -v d
```

I pass the PAT token as follows:

```
docker build --build-args pat_token=$env:PAT_TOKEN
```

Restore fails as the %NUGET_PAT% environment variable doesn't seem to be valid. If I hardcode the PAT Token it works.

I know the value NUGET_PAT is set as I echo it out and it's the correct value. However the restore fails.

I think where I've set `ENV` and `ARG` mean this is in the correct image layer i.e. `Build`. So what's going on?

Comment: What about `NUGET_USER`? I don't see where you set/pass this variable.

Comment: NUGET_USER doesn't need to be set for accessing NuGet feeds with PAT tokens.

I found the solution. 

docker build --build-args NUGET_PAT=$env:PAT_TOKEN

Ensure your docker file has 
ARG NUGET_PAT defined in the build layer.

Ensure your NuGet.config uses the NUGET_PAT environment variable. 

HTH